Unable to Set Cookie using NodeJS in Browser Application tab even its coming in response and also unable to use cookie in subsequent request
I am trying to store the auth token in the cookie once the user logged into the system. Then I want to use the auth token for subsequent requests. When I console ('req.cookies':  req.cookies) the output is [Object: null prototype] {}
I have tried a lot but was unable to solve the issue, I got the set-cookie in the response header but not on the Application Tab of the console. However, it works fine with Postman.
Frontend is running on: http://merchant.localhost:3000
Backend is running on: http://127.0.0.1:8080
I'm using cookie-parser
I have configured the cors and cookie-parser as follows.
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://merchant.localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,
}));

This is how I have stored the token in the cookie.
res.cookie("authToken", authToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        sameSite: "None",
        domain: "localhost",
      });

Below is the image of my response header.

Below is the image of the Application Tab.

for subsequent requests, I pass credentials: 'include', but still it is not working.
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/produce/add", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: 'include',
      body: formData,
    }) 

I have tried clearing the cookies and browsing data and with different browsers. Also, tried with the incognito tab as well. But, nothing works.
